# Tour Of Heroes - Why are messages updated?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular.io and playing around with the application tour of heroes, not following completely the tutorial and trying a bit different things.
There is some magic happening which I do not get. If I add a message using the MessageService when selecting an hero, the message list gets updated with new messages. Problem is that I do not see why as in the message component, I am calling getMessages() only in ngOnInit(), and my message component has its own list of messages. I am not displaying directly the ones of the service. So why do they get displayed?

Somehow it seems the list of messages that I have in my message component gets coupled to the list of messages which is in my message service but why?

message.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMessages();
  }

  getMessages(): void {
    this.messages = this.messageService.getMessages();
  }

  clear(): void {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.getMessages();
  }
}
```

message.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="messages.length">

  <h2>Messages</h2>
  <button class="clear"
          (click)="clear()">clear</button>
  <div *ngFor='let message of messages'> {{message}} </div>

</div>
```

heroes.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService,
              private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
    this.messageService.add('Select hero');
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }

  getMessages() {
    return this.messages;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is in the object reference. In the NgOnInit you only give the reference to the messages array and when the service adds a message to the array. The array in the component pointing to the same array will get the new message as well beause it is the same array in the RAM.

For more info look here:
https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php

Comment: Ok, I guess I was never doing much with javascript...Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Angular Tour of Heroes docs -

> Modify the constructor with a parameter that declares a private messageService property. Angular will inject the singleton MessageService into that property

What is happening is that the dependency is being injected via the parameter request in the constructor. The ngOnInit calls getMessages. Since the messenger server is a singleton, meaning there is only one instance of it throughout the application, ultimately the getMessages of your messenger service are being called on init of your message component.